# how can I use util:list in spring configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use spring's unmarshaller to automatically unmarshal request body from xml to an object. But I failed getting the error `util` prfeix unbind. Could you tell me how can I use `util:list` and where can I find reference for `util:list`.

I did spot that the official documentation leave out a closing `>` in `</property` and I correct that in my configuration.

I find configuration far more frustrating that just write the code.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </util:list>
    </property
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare to util namespace; e.g.:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly the problem.